# How to expose internal System.Array

Tags: c#

I have a class that is a container for two fixed length arrays as well as some other members.  I want to expose the elements of the array for assignment outside the class.

Example would be:

```
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    class ArrayContainer<T, U>
    {
       private T[] x;
       private U[] y;

       // Some other members and constructor

       public Collection<T> X
       {
            get { return new Collection<T>(this.x); }
       }

       public Collection<U> Y
       {
           get { return new Collection<U>(this.y); }
       }
    }
```

If I try to do instance.X[i] = value I get an exception saying the collection is readonly.  So I have three questions:

1. Why can't I make the above assignment?
2. Is this the correct was to expose internal members?
3. Are there any performance issues with making a "new" Collection every time the array is created?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just return the array directly on `get`?

Comment: Btw, `2DArrayContainer` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @jheddings: it isn't appropriate to return an array directly using a getter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Not sure, but since you are returning a new Collection, it doesn't matter what you do to it. The changes will be lost once the Garbage Collector deletes the Collection. Changes made to the collection will not affect the original array.
2. No, the correct way would be to either expose the arrays directly, or, if you're worried clients won't play nice, expose them via getters and setters. Since C# only allows 1 property per class with arguments you'll have to use functions for this:

   ```
   instance.SetX(int index, T value);
   T val = instance.GetX(int index);
   ```
3. Yes, making copies always takes extra time and memory. If this is performance critical code, this solution is not acceptable, otherwise, it's probably fine.

Comment: This seems to be the only valid way to do this.  I was hoping I could allow access to 'X' and 'Y' via properties due to the cleaner interface.  I guess not...

Comment: @Brian, you could, but you'd have to switch to VB (I believe C# in .NET 4.0 also supports properties with arguments). Then you can make two properties which accept an integer (index) and which access the arrays internally. One of those few areas where VB actually seems to be more mature than C#...

Comment: Point #1 is incorrect. Collection<T>, when given an IList<T>, only wraps the original item. All changes to the original are shown through the collection, and all changes to the collection are shown through the array. The problem in @Brian's instance with the NotSupportedException is due to the SZArrayHelper wrapper returned as the IList<T> implementation for arrays. SZArrayHelper returns true for IsReadOnly. For #2, it is never correct to expose an array directly. You should only return a copy. Hiding this with a SetValue() style is fine however.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to 3: 
Your performance is definitely at issue; you'd be creating a new instance each time it was accessed. Any time a person wrote a for... loop you'd get a new instance for each iteration.

Why not publicly just expose your collections? I might do the same thing by simply using List:

```
class Data<T,U> {
    public List<T> X = new List<T>();
    public List<U> Y = new List<U>();
}
```

Writing code would be quite simple:

```
        Data<int, string> theData = new Data<int, string>();
        // add
        theData.X.Add(37);
        theData.Y.Add("foo");
        // access
        theData.X[0] = 42;
        theData.Y[0] = "bar";
        // as an array
        int[] x = theData.X.ToArray();
```

If performance really creeps you out, just use arrays instead of List<T>.

Comment: I understand foo, bar, and 42, but is there a reason for picking 37? Or is it just a handy random number?

Comment: If you run this through FxCop you'll get a DoNotExposeGenericList Error.  The rationale is explained here: http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2006/04/27/faq-why-does-donotexposegenericlists-recommend-that-i-expose-collection-lt-t-gt-instead-of-list-lt-t-gt-david-kean.aspx

Comment: @Brian Triplett, point well taken. I don't use FxCop as a universal authority but the link has meaningful reasoning that should be considered. 

@Martinho, I like lucky primes.

Answer (score 0):

If you familiar with concept of interfaces, then you can choose or code the interface explaining what should be external. Then add interface to you class declaration and compiler will help you to do the rest of things properly since.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what this is for, but why not use indexers or getter/setter methods? I would think that that would be the typical way of doing this.